# Jquery selector on a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use jQuery to select attributes and elements of some html code, alter them with jQuery, and then append that edited html code in the DOM.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
var codeExample = $(".stuff").html();
$(codeExample).attr("id").val("2412");
$(codeExample).find("div #foo").attr("rel").val("bar");
$("#element").append(codeExample);
```

Is that possible? Or I first have to insert the html code in the DOM, and then find it with jQuery and edit it?

Comment: That's entirely possible. Do you have an issue with it?

Comment: is my dummy code right?

Comment: You need to store `codeExample` as a jQuery object, not a string. It would also depend on how the DOM is structured as to whether or not it would work as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var codeExample = $(".stuff");
codeExample.attr("id", "2412");
codeExample.find("div#foo").attr("rel", "bar");
```

Though your `id` and `rel` are already modified. But if you still want to append it to `#element` do the following:

```
$("#element").append(codeExample);
```

Comment: my mistake was that var codeExample was undefined, and it was crashing after that, but you gave me some good ideas, so cheers

Comment: Thanks :) Please mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1):

As Rory states in the comment, your code will work and should have no problems, but as you want to replace the content already placed in DOM, it might be useful to use `$('.stuff').replaceWith(codeExample);` instead.

You can find more about `replaceWith()` in [the jQuery documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).